# Negative statement in hypothesis

Tags: regression

I want to test the hypothesis: risk-taking increases when managers get negative feedback. 
My professor told me to be careful with the results, since I have negative statement, so if P is smaller, than 0,05 it means that actually they are not increasing risk-taking.
Second part of the hypothesis was that the more experience managers have the more risk-taking they will apply once getting negative feedback. I've been asked to multiply negative feedback by their experience and then tests whether risk-taking is increasing... Question: once it's multiplied with another variable should I still consider P smaller than 0,05 as not supporting my hypothesis. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CV.  I think you may be confused. I think you probably want to test the null hypothesis that risk taking doesn't change when managers give negative feedback and you want to use a one sided test. If you actually want to test the null that

> risk-taking increases when managers get negative feedback

then you can look into inferiority testing.

The basic ideas stay the same, but it can get a little confusing.

Remember that the null is what you want to *reject*; that is you are hoping that the null is false.

Answer (score 0):

The significance level of your test ( $p < 0.05$), does not need to be changed in such cases. It holds no direct relation to what you are measuring, it represents the probability that you falsely reject your hypothesis.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I`m not sure I explained my question right. So i test my hypothesis and get p<0,05. As I understood from google what I tested is supported. But since my hypothesis is: there is a positive relationship between risk-taking and negative feedback, professor told me that p<0,05 would mean i don't support my hypothesis. I just don't know how to interpret results. I have to multiply negative feedback and experience, and test new independent variable with risk-taking as dependent. Because after doing my tests I get p=0,000.. so does it mean they increase risk-taking or they don't increase risk-taking?

Comment: Interpreting results of such tests remains the same. The obtained p-value suggests that the data does not support your hypothesis. That would mean there would be no evidence to support that more experienced manager increase risk-taking after receiving negative feedback.